# Django template: Slicing form fields into 2 parts

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I'm passing a `form` to my template, using `django-filter` and can be accessed in the template using `filter.form`.

I'm trying to slice the filter form to only show 10 most popular tags. Why is the following now working?

```
# template.html
{% for field in filter.form.tags | slice:"0:10" %}
{{ field }} {{ field.label_tag }}
```

I get the error:

> 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for tags in
>   filter.form.tags | slice:":"

Isn't `x=field` and `y = filter.form.tags | slice:"0:10"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be spaces in `filter.form.tags | slice:"0:10"`, try this:

```
{% for field in filter.form.tags|slice:"0:10" %}
```